# Some compactness related property

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be a topological space. It is known that $X$ is compact if and only if every family of closed sets satisfying [the finite intersection property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_intersection_property) has nonempty intersection.

Is there some kind of compactness property that is equivalent to the following:

> $(P)$ every countable family of closed sets $\left\{F_{i}:i=1,2,3,\ldots \right\}  $ such that $F_{1}\supseteq F_{2}\supseteq F_{3}\supseteq\ldots$ has nonempty intersection.

Clearly, if $X$ is compact, then $(P)$ is satisfied. Another question: is the converse also true (for some particular classes of topological spaces)?

Comment: I think that you have the inclusions going the wrong way: as you’ve written it, the intersection is equal to $F_1$.

Comment: You probably want $\ldots F_3 \subset F_2 \subset F_1$, otherwise $F_1$ is their intersection (and is non-empty).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you. I've made the corrections to the initial post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A space is called countably compact iff every countable open cover has a finite subcover. This translates to (taking complements): every countable family of closed sets with the finite intersection property, has non-empty intersection.

Your property is equivalent to this: if it holds, and we have a countable family of such closed sets $G_n$, we can define $F_n = \cap_{i=1}^n G_i$ which is non-empty, and decreasing. By this property you state, it has non-intersection, which is also the intersection of the $G_n$. Of course, if $X$ is countably compact, your decreasing family has FIP, and so non-empty intersection.

So your property is just a reformulation of countable compactness. This is a well-studied property.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want $(P)$ to say that if $\{F_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a family of non-empty closed sets in $X$ such that $F_n\supseteq F_{n+1}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, then $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}F_n\ne\varnothing$.

This property is equivalent to countable compactness of $X$: every open cover of $X$ has a countable subcover. To see this, let $\mathscr{U}=\{U_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ be a countable family of open sets in $X$ such that no finite subfamily of $\mathscr{U}$ covers $X$. For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $$F_n=X\setminus\bigcup_{k\le n}U_k\;;$$

then $F_n\supseteq F_{n+1}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, and the sets $F_n$ are closed and non-empty. Clearly $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}F_n\ne\varnothing$ iff $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n=X$, i.e., iff $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X$ with no finite subcover.